# Adding 2 array tables together

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im trying to grab all the users status from my website.
Here is my table
[image]

If i add another user my username gets added into user1
If another user adds me there username gets added into user1 and mine into user2

So i need to try and grab all the ids from user1 and user2 were accepted is 1

which i do like so

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
$yes = '1';
     $query = $db2->prepare("SELECT * FROM friend_requests WHERE (user1='".$id."' OR user2='".$id."') AND accepted = '".$yes."'");
    $query->execute();
 foreach ($query as $row) {
        print $row['user1'] . "\t";
        print $row['user2'] . "\t";

    }
```

But now i have $row['user2'] and $row['user1'] is there any way of putting these together into one ? So i can simply do a pdo loop select status were id = that ?

Im trying to grab all status were id = $row['user1'] or $row['user2'] but i dont want to use or in my pdo select.

Comment: you are using `->prepare()` but still directly injecting data into the query? Why??

Comment: I only using the users id which is made safe before its put into  session. They $yes i make my self

Comment: A good way to go about queries in PHP is to ***ALWAYS*** use prepapred statements for ***EVERY LAST QUERY*** that way if you change a query to use user submitted data, you won't accidentally open up a security hole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit your SQL as follows:

```
"SELECT id, (CASE WHEN user1 = $id THEN user2 ELSE user1 END) as user, time FROM friend_requests WHERE (user1 = $id OR user2 = $id) AND accepted = 1"
```

This will return just the accepted friends for your user with id $ID.

Proof of concept here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b337/2

**EDIT**: As has been pointed out, you should bind parameters to protect against SQL injection, but that's outside the scope of your question.

**EDIT 2**: Per your second question below you can either do two loops or, if the table is small relative to available memory, you can do a fetchAll() as follows.

```
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
$query = $db2->prepare("SELECT (CASE WHEN user1 = :userid THEN user2 ELSE user1 END) as user FROM friend_requests WHERE (user1 = :userid OR user2 = :userid) AND accepted = 1");
$query->bindParam(':userid', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$friends = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$friends[] = array('user'=>$id);
foreach ($friends as $k=>$friend) {
    echo $friend . "\t";
}
```

Comment: Then there all in $row['user']  ?? Just printed $row['user'] and there all there :) There was duplicates in the db which the above code doesn't show which is good.

Comment: Yes all accepted friends of the user with id=$id will be in the $row['user'] variable.

Comment: Is there any way i can add my own id to $row['user'] so it shows my own status to ? Did try array_push($row['user'], '12'); but 12 didnt get added

Comment: Yes you could just change the query to:
`"SELECT $id as me, id, (CASE WHEN user1 = $id THEN user2 ELSE user1 END) as user, time FROM friend_requests WHERE (user1 = $id OR user2 = $id) AND accepted = 1"`

Comment: Didn't work :( shows others but not me also removes a few

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to just add a column with 12 in it to each row?

Comment: The above code the first one which ive marked correct works. It adds all users who are my friends into $row['user'] so inside $row['user'] there is muti user ids. I just need my id added once into $row['user'] so basically im friends with myself

Comment: above code still doesn't work for the logged in sure but i found out why. My id is not in the friends table so i added my id and added accepted = 1 and your code worked http://prntscr.com/jemf5i My id is 12 i had to do this inside the table for your code to work so im guessing ill have to add it when each users registers it adds there id into both columns and accepted = 1 no problem for me :)

Comment: also it says$friends[] = ['user'=>$id];  there is a error?

Comment: If using an earlier version of php you need array() syntax. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`:

```
<?php

$id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
$yes = '1';
$query = $db2->prepare("SELECT id,user2 AS `user` FROM `friend_requests` WHERE user1=:user1 AND accepted={$yes} UNION SELECT id,user1 AS `user` FROM `friend_requests` WHERE user2=:user2 AND accepted={$yes}");
$query->bindParam(':user1', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(':user2', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$query->execute();
foreach ($query as $row) {
    print $row['user'] . "\t";
}
```

Example: [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0b337/4)

Comment: Is there any way i can add my own id to $row['user'] so it shows my own status to ? Did try array_push($row['user'], '12'); but 12 didnt get added